# How to insert AET in mysql time_zone tables

Tags: mysql, timezone

There are two ways to install timezone info in mysql db.
1) with file provided by mysql
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
2) from os files in /usr/share/zoneinfo
but as of now both doesn't contain AET info.

Can you please help how to install AET in mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're asking about [Australia Eastern Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aet). You can get that from the ordinary zoneinfo database using `Australia/Sydney` for jurisdictions that switch from standard to daylight time. `Australia/Brisbane` gives you jurisdictions that stay on standard time all year.

There's no need to insert an extra zone. Plus, you don't want to be responsible for maintaining it. It's a notorious pain in the neck.

The [zoneinfo database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) was [last updated on July 5, 2016](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-July/000040.html).